# Display image in Vue from storage folder with laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-5, vuejs2

I'm saving my images in following location

> Storage/app/public/userImages

It is getting saved but when i retrieve it in my vue component it throws error 404 not found.

```
<img :src="`/storage/${post.img_path}`"/>
```

and the url which is created is

```
http://localhost:8000/storage/userImages/872937058.png
```

Please give any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a method to your controller (e.g. `PostController`):

   ```
   use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

   /**
    * Display the specified resource.
    *
    * @param \App\Post $post
    * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\BinaryFileResponse
    * @throws \Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException
    */
   public function image(Post $post)
   {
       return response()->file(
           Storage::disk('local')->path($post->img_path)
       );
   }
   ```
2. Add a route to `routes/web.php`:

   ```
   Route::get('/posts/{post}/image', 'PostController@file')->name('posts.image');
   ```
3. Use it like this:

   ```
   <img :src="`/posts/${post.id}/image`"/>
   ```

Comment: Can you please tell what to pass in last parameter, i'm storing path like this in db img_upload/629806533.png where img_upload is folder and 629806533 is the image

Comment: @user3653474 which parameter you mean? you should pass this path as `Storage::disk('local')->path('img_upload/629806533.png')` on the item 1.

Comment: <img :src="`/posts/${post.id}/image`"/> what to pass in this image parameter

Comment: image is not a parameter it's just a part of the URL I've defined in the route: `Route::get('/posts/{post}/image', 'PostController@file')->name('posts.image');`

Answer (score 0):

The first step, you should install

```
php artisan storage:link
```

In your vue file, you can use a regular img tag

```
<img :src="`/storage/${post.img_path}`" />
```

or,

```
<img :src="`/storage/userImages/${imageName}`" />
```

Note: You do not need to add "app/public" to the src attribute